# Bayes theorem for two continuous random variable, question about the domains

Tags: probability

I think its better to explain it by example : 
there is a circle with a radious that is distributed uniformly in [0,8]

i.e, $R\sim U[0,8]$.

We chose a random point $M$ in the circle, and let $X$ be the distance from the center of the circle to the point $M$

now - I want to find $f(R|X)$ - I found that $f(X|R)=\frac{2x}{R^2}$ and then from Bayes theorem $f(R|X)=\frac{f(X|R)f(R)}{f(X)}$ and also $f(X|R)=\frac{f(X,R)}{f(R)}$ so we get $f(X,R)$ - now to get $f(X)$ we need to integrate $f(X,R)$ from -$\infty$ to $\infty$ with respect to $X$

what I dont understand is why the integral limits become $X$ to $8$ and not $0$ to $8$

this bugs me for a while, and I just know it should be like that, but cant explain it...

thanks!

Comment: The density function of $R$ **given** that $X=x$ is $0$ for $r\;t x$.

Comment: you meant r=x ?

Comment: Ouch, typo. It was the density function of $R$ given that $X=x$ is $0$ for $r\lt x$.

Comment: ok, but what about the regions of 0 to x, why are we ignoring them?

Comment: ok, got it now - we are looking for r, and if we have X we know that R will be from X to R. the penny has dropped....thanks!!!!

Comment: You are welcome. In probability calculations, it can be a tricky thing to remember that a formula one has obtained is valid only for a resricted domain.